# Switching between versions when using Ansible git single_branch doesn't work

Tags: git, ansible

I have an issue where I'm using Ansible to sync my git repo once with a dev-branch ( `dev` )
But then i want to switch back to the `main` branch it gets stuck with the previous sync, and since i'm using `single_branch = yes` only the branch I requested gets into the server.

```
- name: Clone www websites
      remote_user: "myuser"
      git:
        clone:  yes
        update: yes
        single_branch:  yes
        accept_hostkey: yes
        repo: "ssh://server/{{ item.key }}.git"
        dest: "/www/{{ item.key }}"
        version: "{{ item.value.version | default(HEAD) }}"
      with_dict: "{{ www_sites }}"
```

The variables i'm passing the first time is:

```
vars:
  www_sites:
    firstwww:
        port: 8080
        uri:  "/path/"
        version: "dev"      # dev is the name of the branch
```

To the server now I have a single branch synced called `dev`

Not i'm switching the variable to:

```
vars:
  www_sites:
    firstwww:
        port: 8080
        uri:  "/path/"
        version: "main"      # This is after I merged the dev -> main in my git server
```

Then it throw the errors:

```
"fatal: 'origin/main' is not a commit and a branch 'main' cannot be created from it"
```

As it is really not synced during the first run of Ansible, when running Ansible with the `main` change it try to do `git checkout main` but there's no `main` due to the first time where i synced only `dev` ...

Adding `force: yes` doesn't help overridi

To solve it - I manually go to the server and remove the directory - running it again - sync the `main` as I requested from Ansible playbook.

So how I'm suppose to use this process correctly so I wouldn't need to login to the server to remove the directory, and I can also "play" with the branches to test my changes in the server before requesting a merge ?

Comment: If you do want easy access to all the original branch names (now `origin/*` names), don't use single-branch mode when cloning: it's really that simple.

Comment: [_The repository named in repo is not appended to this path and **the destination directory must be empty**._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/git_module.html#parameter-dest): to me the docs are pretty clear about this

Comment: use a `file` module with the `state: absent` in a task before hand to remove the directory instead of logging on the server, though